# Algorithm to solve allocation conflicts - is it NP?

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization

Please help solve or point me to the appropriate existing algorithm in theory for this problem.
No, it is not a coding contest, it comes from a real life issue!
Here it is :

**We have a list of tasks to do.
Every task has a start day, end day, and a profit.
Some tasks collide (their days within start end end dates intersect), therefore one can only do one at a time, so a choice has to be made.
How can one select tasks to optimize profit?**

I googled but could not find the related problem. Sure it exists.
Thanks for help!

Comment: [interval scheduling problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_scheduling)

Comment: Or it could be mapped to Maximum Weight Independent Set by creating a graph with edges between tasks that do intersect. It would be an interval graph, which makes the problem much easier: [Maximum Weight Independent Set on Interval Graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_scheduling#Weighted)

Comment: Whether this problem can be mapped to a different problem is not the issue here. The question is whether those problems can be formulated and solved as the problem specified by the OP. That is what is needed to prove NP Hardness of the OP's problem. In any case, that is moot, since the OP's problem is polynomially solvable. A problem in P can always be framed and solved as a different problem that is known to be NP Hard.

Answer (score 1):

This is polynomially solvable since this can be solved as a linear program. From your OP, it appears that each task covers *consecutive* days of work, and each day, only one task can be worked on. Given this, index your tasks by `i = 1,...,I`. Let profit be `p_i`. Let `j = 1,...,J` index the total number of days.

Then, you have the following problem to solve (specialized for 3 tasks and 4 days each task taking 2 consecutive days)

```
Max p_1 x_1 + p_2 x_2 + p_3 x_3
s.t.
    x_1                        <= 1 // day 1 task 1 
    x_1  + x_2                 <= 1 //day 2 task 1 or 2
           x_2   + x_3         <= 1 //day 3 task 2 or 3
                   x_3         <= 1 //day 4 task 3
x_1, x_2, x_3 >= 0
```

Next, convert each inequality to an equality by adding a slack variable.

```
Max p_1 x_1 + p_2 x_2 + p_3 x_3
s.t.
    x_1                + s_1               = 1 
    x_1  + x_2              + s_2          = 1 
           x_2   + x_3           + s_3     = 1
                   x_3                +s_4 = 1
                                         0 = 0
x_1, x_2, x_3, s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4 >= 0
```

Now, this is the same as:

```
Max p_1 x_1 + p_2 x_2 + p_3 x_3
s.t.
    x_1                + s_1                    = 1 
        x_2            - s_1 + s_2              = 0 
   -x_1     + x_3            - s_2 + s_3        = 0
       -x_2                        - s_3 + s_4  = 0
            - x_3                        - s_4  = -1
x_1, x_2, x_3, s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4 >= 0
```

where we have kept the first equation as is, and then sequentially subtracted the previous equation from the current one iteratively. If you observe the constraint matrix, you will observe that each column has exactly one +1 and exactly one -1 entry as the non-zero entries (this is a totally unimodular matrix). As a result, this becomes a trivial linear program, a network flow problem, that can be very efficiently solved by the network simplex method.

Note: On some thought it should be clear that even if different tasks span different number of days, performing the operation as indicated above will always lead to a totally unimodular constraint matrix.

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty easy O(N<sup>2</sup>) dynamic programming solution.

Let **BEST(d,w)** be the maximum profit that you can attain using jobs with start days <=d, and end days < d+w.

Assuming that all start days are >=0, then **BEST(0,w) = 0** for all **w**.

For all the other days, **BEST(d,w)** for any **d** and all **w** can be easily calculated from the values for **BEST(d-1,w+1)** and the list of tasks that start on day **d**.

When *d* is high enough that all jobs have been considered, then the max **BEST(d,w)** is your answer.

With a little extra effort, you can limit your calculations to days on which tasks start, and lengths (w values) that are different from the next shorter length.  That limits the range of both values to the number of jobs.

Comment: Can you be more precise Matt please ? I suppose you presume days are > 0 to be able to say that BEST(0,w) = 0.  Besides, can you provide the formula for BEST(d,w) from BEST(d-1, <to be defined>) ? The way you put it it even seems w can be discarded ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually.... You just need to Google
"Weight interval scheduling"
... And you get a nice simple algorithm on YouTube for instance.
( I put this for people with same worry as mine that will arrive here )
Thanks everyone.